# How would I resolve a large batch of redirect URLs?

Tags: microsoft-excel, url, url-shortening

I have a .csv file will 1000s of aliased/shortened links (such as bit.ly etc.). I need to find out where they redirect to. Is there a simple program that could complete this task?

Comment: uhm, what has excel to do with this ?

Comment: I figured there might be a formula or macro I don't know about. Other than that, nothing.

Comment: I would start with looking at `wget` and `curl`. Maybe with the `--spider` option. That is only half the solution though.

Answer (score 2):

If you can find a way to save the file as plaintext with one url per line, you could use the following script on a Linux/MacOS/*nix machine or [Cygwin](http://cygwin.com/) on Windows to spit out a text file with the urls.

```
#!/bin/bash
rm resolved_urls.txt
for url in $(cat url.txt); do
        wget -S "$url" 2>&1 | grep ^Location >> resolved_urls.txt
done
```

Copy the above text into a file called resolve.sh using `nano` if you need to, make it executable with `chmod +x resolve.sh`, name the file with bit.ly URL's and etc to url.txt, ensuring it is in the same folder as the resolve.sh file, and execute it with `./resolve.sh`. It will create a file called "resolved_urls.txt" with the original URL and it's resolved counterpart.

The output with

```
http://bit.ly/1auRnQ9
http://bit.ly/19ZkTAI
```

in url.txt is

```
http://bit.ly/1auRnQ9 --> Location: http://www.google.com/ [following]
http://bit.ly/19ZkTAI --> Location: http://superuser.com/ [following]
```

**This script is far from perfect and may invoke the wrath of various Unix greybeards**, but it at least works for bit.ly. Let me know if you have any *nix related questions.

Comment: shouldn't be too hard to reprocess a csv into a plain text file, just needs some naughty business with cut

Comment: Couldn't you just use `wget -S` and get the server response without the output. Then there is no need for the `delete_me`. And you could even do `wget -S $url 2>&1 | grep ^Location >> resolved_urls.txt` in one line. (Also no need for log.txt :)

Comment: Thanks, Rik. I thought there would probably be a flag for doing that, but didn't want to spend too long on this problem. :P

Answer (score 2):

You didn't specify your OS.

But in Linux (with Curl and awk installed) you can do something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read LINE ; do
  NEWURL=$(curl -sIL $LINE 2>&1 | awk '/^Location/ {print $2}' | tail -n1;)
  echo "$LINE ; $NEWURL"
done < urls.txt
```

Note that sites who don't redirect will not have a result after the old one.

Answer (score 1):

http://linkpeelr.appspot.com/ does it onscreen, but there's an API you can use at http://longurl.org/